# Mouseover Event not working well with overlaid objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create mouseover tooltip effects on the graph created by d3. The circle is on top of the line. The problem I meet is that when the mouse is actually on the position of the line, the tooltip is disappeared. Is there a way to ignore the background line?

Mouseover is not triggered because the mouse is pointed at the background line:

[image]

Mouseover is triggered:
[image]
I have a on mouseover function like this:

```
.on("mouseover", function(thisElement, index){
  //do something when it is selected
})
```

Comment: It seems like you have `mouseover` event to the circle. You can use `z-index` to make the circle remain at `top` of all other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not planning to use the line path for any other events, the most straightforward way when it comes to solving such issues would be to allow the mouse event of the line to propagate. We can make use the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) CSS property, and set its value as `none`.

You apply it on your JavaScript code,

```
.style('pointer-events', 'none')
```

Or configure it via CSS (Do not that this may not work if you are working with JavaScript frameworks such as Angular, due to encapsulation)

```
.line {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `line` is on top of `circle`. You can change the stack order by using `z-index`.

Example - 
I have attached the `mouseover` event to `box1` and partial section of `box2` is on top of `box1`.

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
div1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('Triggering');
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    /* z-index: 2; */
    position: relative;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    /* z-index: 1; */
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">Box1</div>
<div id="box2">Box2</div>
```

Setting `z-index` of `box1` higher than `box2`.

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
div1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('Triggering');
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">Box1</div>
<div id="box2">Box2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a simple solution: set  pointer-events: "none" for the background items