# Send mouseover event to all overlaid elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Does anyone know how to propagate/trigger the `mouseover` event to multiple children when they appear overlaid on top of each other? Is it even possible?

I'm trying to get `mouseover` to be triggered for 2 overlaid elements. I've written a basic example to demonstrate the problem:

[image: example-output]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }
    .relative {
      position: relative;
    }
    .child-1,
    .child-2 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    .child-1 {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
    }
    .child-2 {
      top: 50px;
      left: 50px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
  </style>

  <body class="relative">
    <div class="child-1">1</div>
    <div class="child-2">2</div>
  </body>

  <script>
    const child1 = document.querySelector('.child-1');
    const child2 = document.querySelector('.child-2');

    child1.addEventListener('mousemove', () => console.log(1));
    child2.addEventListener('mousemove', () => console.log(2));
  </script>
</html>
```

Whenever I hover over just child 1, I get a log of `1`. When I hover over just child 2, I get a log of `2`. That all works. But when I hover over 1 and 2 where they overlap, I only get a log of which ever one is on top, in this case `2` (this can be flipped by adjusting the `z-index` or order in the DOM).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086916/mouseover-event-not-working-well-with-overlaid-objects), but changing the `z-index` or `pointer-events: none` doesn't help me because I need both the element's event to fire.

Comment: See [`elementsFromPoint`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint).

Comment: Yuck, that's not gonna be very convenient to work with, but I suppose it can get the job done :/ Thanks

Comment: Seems easy: `document.querySelector(".relative").addEventListener("mousemove", ({ x, y }) => document.elementsFromPoint(x, y).forEach(console.log));`.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get it working, but I ended up going for a different approach. Cool API to know about though, thanks for sharing.